# Component props are undefined in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am passing a props to one my views but when I print the result in console it send me as undefined, but in the view it print me the id  because the undefined I can't do request/consults this is the code:

```
export default {
  props: ['idVideo'],
  data: () => ({
    videos: []
  }),
  created() {
    //do something after creating vue instance
    this.api = new ApiCanal10({})
    this.getRelVideos()

  },
  methods: {
    getRelVideos: function() {
     //print in the console
      console.log(`video/related/${this.idVideo}`)
    }
  }
}
```

this is an image with the print in the view and the console send me as undefined
[image]

I will really appreciate if you can help me with this issue.

Comment: You have an error exception before the printing. are u sure it has nothing to do with that?

Comment: that's a warning for a local player but it is a different component it doesn't affect the project in self

Answer (score 0):

See [camelCase vs. kebab-case](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case):

> HTML attributes are case-insensitive, so [...] camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-case (hyphen-delimited) equivalents:
>
> ```
> Vue.component('child', {
>   // camelCase in JavaScript
>   props: ['myMessage'],
>   template: '<span>{{ myMessage }}</span>'
> })
>
>
> <!-- kebab-case in HTML -->
> <child my-message="hello!"></child>
> ```

Thus you need to bind your component property as follows:

```
<component-name :id-video="someVar"></component-name>
```

Comment: "Again, if you’re using string templates, then this limitation does not apply." Neither does it apply to single file components, which it appears the OP is using.

Comment: what I did update the father request with an update like this --> updated(){
    this.getRelVideos()
  }, an then I call it like with a method :-->  methods: {
    getRelVideos: function() {}
  }

Comment: @JULIOMACHAN Can you clarify and update your question?

Answer (score 0):

To pass the information from the parent to the child I used an update this is the code:

```
export default {
  updated(){
    this.getRelVideos()
  },
  methods: {
    getRelVideos: function() {}
  }
}
```

in that way in the console it show the request.